# Prove that $\int g\ {\rm d} \mu<\infty$?

Tags: integrable-systems

Let $(S,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be aprobability space and $g\ge 0$ with $\int g\ln^+\ln^+ g {\rm d} \mu<\infty$. Can you help me prove that $\int g\ {\rm d} \mu<\infty$?

Comment: what does $\ln^+$ mean?

Comment: Maybe $$\ln^+ x=\ln \mid x\mid?$$

Comment: It means: $\ln^+ x = \max (\ln x,0)$

Comment: and how do you handle expressions like $\ln(0)$ - which can clearly happen?

Comment: I guess it will be like this $\ln^+ 0 = \max (\ln 0,0):=0$, so you don't need to care about what $\ln 0$ is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that, for every $M'\gt0,$ there exists some $M\gt0$ large enough that
$$\{g\ge M\}\subseteq\{g\ln^+\ln^+g\ge M'\}.$$
And by hypothesis $$\int_{g\ln^+\ln^+g\ge M'}g\ln^+\ln^+g\lt\infty.$$
Hence we can choose $M$ more large enough that $\ln^+\ln^+g\ge1$ when $g\ge M.$ Thus
$$\int_{g\ge M}g\le\int_{g\ge M}g\ln^+\ln^+g\le\int_{g\ln^+\ln^+g\ge M'}g\ln^+\ln^+g\lt\infty.$$
Since $\mu(X)=1,$we conclude that
$$\int_Xg=\int_{g\ge M}g+\int_{g\lt M}g\le \int_{g\ge M}g+M\mu(X)\lt\infty.$$

Comment: Can I choose $M=e^e$? Then we have: $$ \int_{g\ge e^e} g \le \int_{g \ge e^e} g \ln^+ \ln^+ g <\infty  $$ and hence $$ \int_{X} g =  \int_{g\ge e^e} g +  \int_{g\le e^e} g \le   \int_{g\ge e^e} g +e^e \mu(X)<\infty. $$

Comment: Oh!!~~Ah ah ah~!! Yes you right ! My proof is too complicated.

Comment: Your proof is great suggestion for me. (y)